# Debug authentication of Bazel's http_file

Tags: bazel

I want to fetch some data in Bazel over HTTP. There's a [http_file method](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.5.0/repo/http.html#http_file) that looks like what I want. The remote server I'm fetching from uses authentication, so I've written it as

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_file")

http_file(
    name = "data_file",
    urls = ["https://example.com/data.0.1.2"],
    sha256 = "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
    downloaded_file_path = "data_file",
)
```

When I try the build, I get

> WARNING: Download from https://example.com/data.0.1.2 failed: class com.google.devtools.build.lib.bazel.repository.downloader.UnrecoverableHttpException GET returned 401 Unauthorized

Followed by fatal errors because the file doesn't exist.

The error makes me think that I'm not authenticating correctly. I have a `.netrc` file and `curl` is able to use it to fetch the file.

Is there a way for me to debug? If it was curl, I would pass `-v` and see the auth header being sent with the request. I'm not sure if bazel is failing to send any authentication or if it's incorrect.

Running Bazel 3.2.0 on Mac OS (Darwin 19.6.0) and on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: I am not aware of a way to debug that but to copy the `http_file` rule  (functions it uses) and instrument it. Your assumptions do sound correct, incorrectly or not at all authenticated access and challenge to authenticate... but few questions come to mind: version of bazel used? (netrc is supported without interruption since 1.0.1) and platform (on Windows this has not made it in until quite a bit later, 3.1 iirc).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added version info. If you move your comment to an answer, I think it's valuable to have answers even/especially when they are "there is no good way to do this thing".

Comment: I'll try to extend it a bit and do so. In the meanwhile, one more question/idea. It may be too obvious, but ownership and access control. I am not sure if all consumers (e.g. `curl`) care the same way: `.netrc` really should be owned by UID under which the process runs and have `0600` permbits... Otherwise depending on implementation it tends to be rejected / ignored and in some cases I suspect that can happen silently. Also correction to previous comment, 1.1 was the version it got (re)introduced.

Comment: Yes, the documentation for .netrc says that it must by 0600 if it contains passwords and Curl does the standard thing there (which is to silently ignore the file if it has the wrong permissions). My request was failing in Curl until I fixed the permissions.

Comment: I've also included the src links in now an answer... One other idea still... does the server support http basic? (verbose `curl` should see what they've agreed on with the server). For other form, [`auth_patterns`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_file-auth_patterns) also needs to get involved. That could also be the cause of netrc was resolved correctly. I presume if I attempt to authenticate by an unsupported method (e.g. http basic), I get 401 and challenge including information which method(s) are expected.

Comment: Yep! I followed your suggestion and was easily able to spot my error -- a typo in the URL that I'd given Bazel. Could have caught that without printing, but I get there faster when I can see which of my guesses are wrong (I could see that Bazel was picking up the right creds from .netrc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 401 indeed sounds like incorrectly or not at all authenticated. `.netrc` should be supported and recognized. If not explicitly specified with `netrc` attribute, `${HOME}/.netrc` would be tried if `HOME` is in the environment and bazel runs on non-Windows host (this has been the case since bazel 1.1; and shortly in 0.29) or `%USERPROFILE%/.netrc` if the variable is in the environment and running on Windows (this has been the case since 3.1). At the risk of stating the obvious, the `.netrc` should be owned by the same UID under which the process using it runs and its permbits should be `0600`. If authentication methods other then http basic are needed, [`auth_patterns`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_file-auth_patterns) attribute needs to be used to configure that.

I am not aware of there being any ready made repository rule debugging facility such as CLI flag, but in this case it should be viable to copy the implementation of of the rule and functions it uses from [`tools/build_defs/repo`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/3.2.0/tools/build_defs/repo), instrument it to get debugging info from it and use that for the purpose. For starters perhaps just `print(auth)` of what `auth = _get_auth(ctx, all_urls)` yielded to see if the that rule got the right idea about how to talk to host in question. It should be a `dict` with `type`, `login`, `password` information for each individual `urls` entries. The magic itself happens in [`use_netrc`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/3.2.0/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl#L292).